# Is there any workaround to allow re-popping of closed questions to the review queue in case of future edits?

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed that this question: [What is qubit and how it can be used to hold information?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/what-is-qubit-and-how-it-can-be-used-to-hold-information) was closed as too broad (which I agree with; it is indeed too broad). However, the OP clarified in their comment that their main intent was to ask as to how using superposition of $1$'s and $0$'s makes a quantum computer faster (i.e. causes to have "more processing capability") than classical computing (which is a reasonable question, at least for beginners).

I felt that I could edit the question to make it more focused on that particular aspect. And also improve the formatting and grammar (some of the question marks are missing). However, from what I know, a closed question once edited is directly pushed to the "review queue". Moreover, a closed question gets only one chance to be edited. That is, if it fails to get opened due to the first edit then it won't be popped again to the review queue in case of future edits ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue#comment35193_256572)). I think this is a problem since while my edit may be able to make it more focused I don't think I can change it sufficiently enough to trigger a re-opening, at least without the OP's consent. Given that the OP is a new and an irregular visitor, I'm not sure they'd bother to correct their question themselves either.

So, in such a case what are our options? Should we just leave such kind of badly-formatted and/or broad closed questions as they are? Or is there any workaround such that the question will get popped to the review queues in case of future edits too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a workaround to getting the post back in review queue multiple times with each incremental change. But even with the gyrations you described, the system sounds like it's working pretty much as it should.

Remember that the review queue isn't *meant* to be the be-all place where every post edit should go. When a post is edited — *every time* it is edited — it also gets bumped back to the top of the front page where (hopefully) attentive users are keeping watch to see what's going on and can reopen the post if it is warranted.

If you feel strongly that a post has been closed incorrectly (or you vastly improve the post to the point where the "normal" level of attention is somehow not enough), you can always post it to meta for further consideration. I'd just be careful about posting too many *"kind of badly-formatted and/or broad closed questions"* with minor improvements; particularly where you're (as you say) "not sure [the author] would bother to correct their question themselves".

Sometimes you can only do so much to help a question; then you have to move on. But that doesn't necessarily mean an end to that subject. If a question is sufficiently interesting, it will likely be asked again — hopefully, in a better format the next time around.